# Showing Correct and Incorrect in a quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascript quiz, it is running fine and shows how many correct answers there is.  However, I need it to also show the incorrect questions with their answers.

```
var score = 0;
var questions = [
    ['Question One?', '1 Answer'],
    ['Question Two?', '2 Answer'],
    ['Question Three?', '3 Answer'],
    ['Question Four?', '4 Answer'],
    ['Question Five?', '5 Answer'],
    ['Question Six?', '6 Answer']
];

var cA = [];

function askQuestion(question) {
    var answer = prompt(question[0], '');
    if (answer == question[1]) {
        alert('Correct!');
        score++;
        cA = question;
    } else {
        alert('Sorry. The correct answer is ' + question[1]);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    askQuestion(questions[i]);
}

var message = 'You got ' + score;
message += ' out of ' + questions.length;
message += ' questions correct.';
document.write('<p>' + message + '</p>' + cA);
```

How do I get I display questions that are wrong with their answer?

Comment: What was the point of that change?

Comment: Use an array and save index of question from questions array in else part;

Comment: @wiredlime2015 to clear out the needless HTML tags you added, remove the JS tag from the title, fix the formatting so that it's easy to read and also remove extra line breaks so people don't need to scroll. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ;)

```js
var score = 0;
var questions = [
  ['Question One?', '1 Answer'],
  ['Question Two?', '2 Answer'],
  ['Question Three?', '3 Answer'],
  ['Question Four?', '4 Answer'],
  ['Question Five?', '5 Answer'],
  ['Question Six?', '6 Answer']
];

var cA = [];
var incorrect = [];

function askQuestion(question, index) {
  var answer = prompt(question[0], '');
  if (answer == question[1]) {
    alert('Correct!');
    score++;
    cA = question;
  } else {
    incorrect.push(index);
    alert('Sorry. The correct answer is ' + question[1]);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  askQuestion(questions[i], i);
}

var message = 'You got ' + score;
message += ' out of ' + questions.length;
message += ' questions correct.<br>' + cA;

message += '<br><br>You answered ' + incorrect.length;
message += ' questions incorrect. These are as follows:';

for(var i in incorrect){
  message += '<p>Q ' + (incorrect[i] + 1) + '. ' + questions[incorrect[i]][0] + '<br>' + questions[incorrect[i]][1] + ' </p>';
}

document.write('<p>' + message + '</p>');
```